# Ruby On Rails, form_for specify one attribute on my own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have the following form_for - structure

```
  <%= form_for Group.new, url: what_to_do_files_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
  <%=f.text_field :group_name, placeholder: "Group Name" %>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary", :name => 'submit' do %> Submit <% end %>
  <button type="button" id="check_all"> Check / Uncheck All</button>
   lalalala

  <%end%>
```

model:

```
class Arraygroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_name, :user_id


    no_whitespace=/^[\S]+$/
    validates :group_name, 
                          :format => { :with => no_whitespace} ,    
                          :uniqueness => { :scope=> :user_id,:case_sensitive => false}
    validates_length_of :group_name, :minimum => 3

end
```

So, I want to be able to client-side-validate the database for the group_name and user_id. 
The problem is that user can only specify the name of the group in a text field and the user_id is 0 then. I want to specify the user_id on my own somehow, for example 
`<% f.user_id => @user_spec_id%>`, where @user_spec_id is predefined and points to the ID of the user. My version doesnt work of course. I have tried something like this as well 
`<% user_id => @user_spec_id%>` but it was wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **You are looking for a hidden_field_tag**

In your view, do the following,

```
<%= hidden_field_tag #{f.object_name}[user_id], @user_spec_id %>
```

Obviously inside your form_for.

When you submit the form, you will see that,
in your params["group"] hash, you added an user_id.

Comment: #{f.object_name}this does not work for me, and just f.object_name[user_id] shows me the following error:An ActionView::Template::Error occurred in arraydbs#searchArrayForGroup:

  undefined local variable or method `user_id' for #<#<Class:0xb2f22f8>:0=
xbe56658>

Comment: Oops, try double quotes.."#{f.object_name}[user_id]"